Lipschitz continuity proof question
I am trying to prove locally Lipschitz continuity of a certain function $f$.
I got up to
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq L|x-y|+ C(x,y),$$ where $|C(x,y)|\leq C$ $\forall x,y$ and $C$ is a constant.

Is this sufficient to prove that $f$ is locally Lipschitz?

If not, is there a general trick I can use to get rid of $C(x,y)$?


Any help would be appreciated!

This is too general - it's true for any bounded function (and some unbounded).

I see. So it is function-specific? I just couldn't get rid of $C(x,y)$, so I was wondering if that is still Lipschitz as long as $C$ is bounded.

If $C$ is a constant, then why does it appear to depend on $x$ and $y?$ Do you mean $C(x,y)$ is a bounded function?

For example, Dirichlet function satisfies your condition with $L = 0.1$ and $C(x, y) = 2$. I strongly doubt such weak restriction can meaningfully help in checkint for Lipschitz continuity.

Ah, my bad. Yes, $C(x,y)$ is a bounded function, meaning $|C(x,y)|\leq C$ $\forall x,y$ where $C$ is a constant.

Maybe you want to add the actual function you are looking at.

I agree with Martin Brandenburg: post your original question as a different question and we can help guide you in the right direction.

Okay, thank you for your help everyone!

The answer is no: for example, $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$ if $x\geq 0;\ f(x) = -\sqrt[3]{-x} $ if $x<0,$ with $L=1$ and $C(x,y)=5$ satisfies your inequality, but it is not Lipschitz continuous, and so you can not "get rid of $C(x,y).$"
